# Is it safe to do gevent monkey patching after importing os?

Tags: python, gevent

I know I should apply gevent monkey patching as soon as possible. But can I safely import `os` first? I dont get any warnings or anything.

```
import os

# here is some code that uses os.getenv(), but not much more,
# but needs to be done before monkey patching

from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()
```